# 802.11s versus IBSS mesh (with layer 3 routing protocol)

Tags: ieee-802.11, ad-hoc-wireless, mesh, olsr

I just learned that you can create a Wi-Fi mesh network either with the "native Wi-Fi mesh standard" 802.11s, or by putting all devices of the network in the IBSS mode and run a layer-3 mesh routing protocol (such as OLSR, B.A.T.M.A.N or bmx6) on them.

Are there any significant advantages of 802.11s over the layer-3 solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions seeking primarily opinion-based answers are off-topic here. You can try to edit your question. Please see the [help] for guidance about this.

Comment: By the way, businesses do not really use wireless mesh because it is not stable enough. Most businesses will use WAPs and WLCs to create a stable Wi-Fi network.

Comment: Changed the question. Hope it's more concrete now.